# Bitcoin Core Re-install- Don't want to Overwrite Chain Previously Downloaded

Tags: bitcoin-core, installation

I have a full Bitcoin chain that I downloaded using Bitcoin Core (v.0.18.0.0, from Ubuntu's launchpad [bitcoin ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebitcoin)).  I've moved to another machine and installed the Snap linked from [BitcoinCore.Org](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/), pointing it at my `.bitcoin` directory.  When I run it, I get the following message.  Before I hit "OK", I want to make sure I'm not going to nuke my already downloaded chain.  Can anyone confirm?

> As this is the first time the program is launched, ... Bitcoin Core will download and store a copy of the Bitcoin block chain....  The wallet will also be stored in this directory.
>
> [ ] use the default data directory
> [x] use a custom data directory
>
> When you click OK, Bitcoin Core will begin to download and process the full Bitcoin block chain (320GB) ....
>
> [ ] Discard blocks after verification, except most recent 2 GB (prune)

Also, it's been a while since I looked, but the Ubuntu PPA stable channel is now saying:

> NOT MAINTAINED. The OS-library linking packages here had a series of issues.
> PLEASE DOWNLOAD DIRECTLY FROM bitcoincore.org ...

Is there any chance running that Snap might cause any issues with my wallet and already downloaded blockchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snap (v.0.20.0) is having various issues, some of which are mentioned [here](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging/issues/48).  As mentioned above, the Ubuntu PPA is saying that it shouldn't be used.  There is apparently a second PPA that is [at least semi-official](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/packaging/issues/36).  That works and doesn't overwrite my chain.